# Does anyone have a script to convert a Chrome Bookmarks file with [sub]*folders into a CVS file?

Tags: json, google-chrome, jq, bookmarks

I want to be able to do Vimdiffs and Vimfolds on Bookmarks files that have been converted to CVS files ie with one description and one uri per line.  However, because the Bookmarks file has multiple levels for the folders, the CSV file will also need fields for the different levels of folder names on each line.

I am new to jq but it seems like it should be able to do this sort of conversion?

Thanks,
Phil.

Comment: Hello Philip, Bienvenu on StackOverflow. Can you give more precision ? Some examples of input file and output result ? What is CVS file ? It is a CSV file ? Can you add some Key as Chrome or Javascript or JSON ?

Comment: I just realised it is more complicated than I thought . .

Comment: ie

Sorry, typo, yes I meant CSV.

eg I was thinking of something like this in the Bookmarks:

Dogs:
- Doberman
- Poodle
Bikes:
- Motorbikes
- - Suzuki
- - Honda
- Bicycles

but to have one record per line doesn't work very well:

Dogs, Doberman
Dogs, Poodle
Bikes, Motorbikes, Suzuki
Bikes, Motorbikes, Honda
Bikes, Bicycles

etc - cramming a tree structure into a CSV file is not as easy as I thought . .

Ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Damn it ! All my formatting got wrapped . .

Comment: I think I will have to think about this a bit more - thanks anyway.

Comment: Can you document what you say in COMMENT directly in QUESTION so that other users that read your post for the first time have immediately complete information. If you are loosing your formatting, it is normal for a COMMENT. The formatting is only possible in Question or Answer. Remark: you have only corrected CVS at one place. CVS is always there in Question and also in title.

Comment: Why are you limited the search of a solution to jQ ? On which system are you working ? It is perhaps more intessant to specify OS that to limit your solution to jQ ! And another remark: I think that for Chrome or Opera, Bookmarks are in a data base not in a file !

Comment: If your issue is tree structure. Assign a numeric value to the level that it exists in the tree and use dot notation in your CSV headers

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use any free tools like: https://json-csv.com/

or json2csv: https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv

If neither of those works, perhaps this approach.

When I need to reconstruct data I write a set of loops that identify each property I want for each line in my CSV. Let's say my JSON has `Name, Email, Phone` but for some reason all are at different object levels in my JSON.

First right a loop that resolves Name, then a loop for Email, and one for Phone. At the end of the first loop call the second, and from the second call the third.

Then you can use `jq -n` which allows to create JSON with no input.

So your CSV output would be like `jq -n '{NewName: .["'$Name'"]}'`

once you have a clean JSON with all data points at the same level CSV conversion is smooth.

Hope this helps